Why is the injected GraphQL context in my request-scoped service undefined
I'm building a NestJs app, that for each single request, needs to setup a third party client instance, which depends on a user-specific access token, which gets resolved through the request headers. A request may call several service methods, and I would like to avoid having to pass the client to each method individually.
So I'm trying to implement a request scoped service that I can resolve in each service method to get access to that third party client instance.
I have a fairly straightforward setup in NestJs.
AppModule:
@Module({
  imports: [
    // config
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    // db
    MikroOrmModule.forRoot(config),
    // gql
    GraphQLModule.forRootAsync<ApolloDriverConfig>({
      driver: ApolloDriver,
      imports: [],
      inject: [],
      useFactory: () => ({
        autoSchemaFile: join(process.cwd(), 'src/schema.gql'),
        context: async ({ req, res }: { req: Request, res: Response }): Promise<GraphQLContext> => { 
          return { 
            req, 
            res,
            auth: { userId: 'xxx' // retrieved from request }
          }
        },
        resolvers: {
          UUID: CustomUuidScalar,
        },
      }),
    }),
    // modules
    UserModule,
    AuthModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}

UserModule:
@Module({
    imports: [MikroOrmModule.forFeature([User]), ThirdPartyModule],
    providers: [UserService, UserResolver, ThirdPartyClientService],
    exports: [UserService]
})
export class UserModule {}

User resolver
@Resolver(() => User)
export class UserResolver {
  constructor(
    private userService: UserService,
  ) {}

  @Query(() => User)
  me(@Context() context: GraphQLContext) {
    return this.userService.getUser(context.auth.userId)
  }
}

UserService (using moduleRef)
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    private readonly moduleRef: ModuleRef,
  ) {}

  async getUser(userId: string, req: any): Promise<User> {
    console.log('getUser')
    // Dynamically resolve the request-scoped ThirdPartyClientService
    // Cannot directly inject because that will break the /graphql route so use moduleRef
    const clientService = await this.moduleRef.resolve(ThirdPartyClientService);
    return clientService.getClient().findUser(userId)
  }
}

ThirdPartyModule
@Module({
    imports: [],
    providers: [ThirdPartyClientService],
    exports: [ThirdPartyClientService],
})
export class ThirdPartyModule {}

ThirdPartyClientService
@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class ThirdPartyClientService {
  private client: ThirdPartyClient;

  constructor(@Inject(CONTEXT) private context: GraphQLContext) { 
    console.log(this.context); // this.context is undefined here!
    this.client = new ThirdPartyClientInstance(this.context.auth.userId)

  }

  getClient() {
    return this.client
  }
}

Why is this.context in ThirdPartyClientService undefined?
Here is a minimal repo that has the same issue.
